# How to check the status of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

I need to check the status of SQL Server. When I say status its not the status for each database, but rather for the whole SQL Server.

I need to know what are the queries running in the server and no. of connections, which query is taking too long.

Can anyone please help me with this..

Comment: you might want to say which exact version of mssql server you've got installed

Comment: You can check from there. I am using that one. You can get information on SQL Server in detail. [Who is Active](http://sqlblog.com/tags/Who+is+Active/default.aspx)

Comment: Flagged for dba.se, but perhaps need more info...

Comment: if you are using PHP myAdmin there is a tab called processes to check these details

Comment: I have only experience with 2008 R2 version, and I use the shipped profiling tools that are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx). There's a plenty good chance someone who knows more than me will answer, but I wanted to help out if I could.

Comment: @rajesh.adhi: I don't think phpMyAdmin works with Microsoft SQL Server.....

Comment: @rajesh.adhi phpMyAdmin is for MySQL, this question is tagged for SQLserver.

Answer (score 4):

You'd have more options here:

- Perfmon (or [ResourceMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191246.aspx) on W7+) for general resource information;
- [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320.aspx) in Management Studio;
- Inside SQL Server:

  - [Glenn Berry's DMV queries](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/january-2012-sql-server-20082008-r2-diagnostic-information-queries/);
  - Adam Machanic's stored procedure [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com).

There are also many other external monitoring tools (some free, some paid) that you can use, but these ones are free and worth mentioning as a first step in your work.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using sp_Whoisactive. That store procedure can give variuos ínformation about what mssql.

> To say I like SP_WhoIsActive is an understatement. This is probably
>   the most useful and effective stored procedure I’ve ever encountered
>   for activity monitoring. The purpose of the SP_WhoIsActive stored
>   procedure is to give DBAs and developers as much performance and
>   workload data about SQL Server’s internal workings as possible, while
>   retaining both flexibility and security. It was written by Boston-area
>   consultant and writer Adam Machanic, who is also a long-time SQL
>   Server MVP, a founder of SQLBlog.com, and one of the most elite
>   individuals who are qualified to teach the Microsoft Certified Master
>   classes.

See more information [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/sp_whoisactive)

or you can also see more information like said in the comments [here](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/01/whoisactive/)

Comment: To add to this suggestion, Kendra has a [useful post](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/01/whoisactive/) of collecting data using sp_WhoIsActive. Take a look!

Answer (score 1):

When you say "I need to know what are the queries running in the server and no. of connections, which query is taking too long. "

There is a DMV for this: [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Note: You must have SQL 2005 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about the queries, you can use SQL Server Profiler (included in the paid SQL Server editions out of the box).

It can show you (for example):

- the exact SQL that was used
- how long did each query take
  (so you can find the long-running ones - for example, you can tell it to log only those queries that took longer than X)

Here are some links to get started:

- [Getting Started tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/)
- [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Status') AS DBStatus
```

The DATABASEPROPERTYX function only allows you to see one element at a time, but this maybe helpful if that is all you need.

Here we can see the Status for the master database by issuing the above query.